# timer not working in class actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, timer

```
   package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

public class MasterContainer extends MovieClip
{
    public var playTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,16);


    public function MasterContainer()
    {
        // constructor code
        t1.setSoundName("drum.mp3");
        t2.setSoundName("pluck.mp3");
        t3.setSoundName("drum.mp3");
        t4.setSoundName("drum.mp3");
        t5.setSoundName("drum.mp3");
        t6.setSoundName("drum.mp3");
        t7.setSoundName("drum.mp3");
        t8.setSoundName("drum.mp3");

        masterPlay.addEventListener(flash.events.MouseEvent.CLICK, handleMasterPlay);
        playTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
    }

    public function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        t1.playSound();
        t2.playSound();
        t3.playSound();
        t4.playSound();
        t5.playSound();
        t6.playSound();
        t7.playSound();
        t8.playSound();
    }

    private function handleMasterPlay(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        trace('bla');

    }


}
}
```

this a chopped version of my class. the error i am getting is:
C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Creative Multimedia\semester 5\Action Script\project\MasterContainer.as, Line 9 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Timer.

C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Creative Multimedia\semester 5\Action Script\project\MasterContainer.as, Line 9 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Timer.

C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Creative Multimedia\semester 5\Action Script\project\MasterContainer.as, Line 9 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Timer.

i dont understand this error any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code sample is invalid or incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
```

Did you miss this?

Comment: thanks that fixed it. i thought import flash.events.TimerEvent; would be sufficient

Comment: You should import any single identifier you are using, so the compiler would know where to search for its description and code. Say you use `Event.ENTER_FRAME`, import `flash.events.Event`, no other import will let you live with this used. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

All errors indicates that the Timer class can't be found - check your import statement it should contain this: `import flash.utils.Timer;`

Comment: thanks that fixed it. i thought     import flash.events.TimerEvent; would be sufficient